# What is the rationale behind the ___store and ___from_store URL query parameter?

Tags: magento-1.9, multistore, url, seo

I need to decide whether I list these query parameters out in Search-Engine-Indexers (like it's advisable for `SID`) or if I can safely remove them from the pre-made templates (language switcher).

With my setup, I provide the store-code for run-type "store" already via the server configuration and therefore I would normally say that `___store` is not needed (technically).

But I wonder a bit about the `___from_store` key and whether it's useful or not.

I've also seen that cookies are used to keep the store code which I think can also be optimized away as the store-code - as written - is already provided via server configuration (environment).

- [Magento multistore, __store and ___from_store in URL](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/53386/magento-multistore-store-and-from-store-in-url)
- [Why does Mage_Catalog_Block_Widget_Link add ___store query parameter?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/6774/why-does-mage-catalog-block-widget-link-add-store-query-parameter)
- https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/85457/how-to-remove-from-store-0-store-uk-from-url

Answer (score 8):

`___from_store` is used somehow to determine the url rewrite of the current page.
Let's me give an example.
You have 2 store views. EN and FR.
In EN you have the url `product.pthml`.
In FR you have the same product respond to `produit.phtml`.

When you are on the EN store view on `product.phtml` and you switch the language you are going go to `product.phtml?___from_store=en`.
You don't have an URL rewrite for `product.phtml` on your FR store (you have only `produit.phtml`) but the page still works.
It works because of `___from_store`.
Magento knows to look for the url rewrite of `product.phtml` on the EN store view, map it internaly to the url `catalog/product/view/id/27` and display the same product but on FR language.